# No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource using Ionic and AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, web-services, cordova, ionic-framework

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http: / /  10.1.25.88 /
>   INSIX.DINSIX.WAP/SVCTimeSheetJson.svc /
>   ListarTimetrackerPo…param0=D033E22AE348AEB5660FC2140AEC35850C4DA997&param1=2014-10-22&param2=1.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http :// 10.1.25.88:8100' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I'm getting this error when I try to access my application through the browser, using "ionic serve" cmd line.

PS: 10.1.25.88 is localhost.

This is the code invoked:

> listarTimetrackerPorData: function (data, cod_profissional_prf) {
>           url_webservice = URL_CONST + 'ListarTimetrackerPorDataJSON?param0=' + CH_TIMETRACKER_CONST +
>   '&param1=' + data + '&param2=' + cod_profissional_prf;
>           return $http.get(url_webservice).then(function (JSONresp) {
>               return JSONresp;
>           });
>       },

What's wrong?

Comment: Run the app in device

Answer (score 0):

This is due to browser security policies, CORS is the process to avoid this kind of error. Learn how to implement this on your server at http://enable-cors.org/.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend testing your application in the browser, but if you insist, you can try adjusting your browser:

https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/

The best way to test is to install it to your device.